# Using google spanner in dataflow 2.3.0

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-spanner

I'm trying to write to spanner some messages from google pub/sub. Writing to bigtable works, so nothing is missing at the fundamental level.

I've upgraded to `google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all` v2.3.0, which includes the SpannerIO sink.

I've basically followed the example for writing from the [API docs of SpannerIO](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.3.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/spanner/SpannerIO.html).

However, I'm getting the exception `internal_static_google_rpc_LocalizedMessage_fieldAccessorTable`

Full stack trace:

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli) on project second-dataflow: An exception occured while executing the Java class. internal_static_google_rpc_LocalizedMessage_fieldAccessorTable
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An exception occured while executing the Java class. internal_static_google_rpc_LocalizedMessage_fieldAccessorTable
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo.execute (ExecJavaMojo.java:339)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: internal_static_google_rpc_LocalizedMessage_fieldAccessorTable
    at com.google.rpc.LocalizedMessage.internalGetFieldAccessorTable (LocalizedMessage.java:87)
    at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3.getDescriptorForType (GeneratedMessageV3.java:121)
    at io.grpc.protobuf.ProtoUtils.keyForProto (ProtoUtils.java:126)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.spi.v1.SpannerErrorInterceptor.<clinit> (SpannerErrorInterceptor.java:47)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.spi.v1.GrpcSpannerRpc.<init> (GrpcSpannerRpc.java:128)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.SpannerOptions$DefaultSpannerRpcFactory.create (SpannerOptions.java:70)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.SpannerOptions$DefaultSpannerRpcFactory.create (SpannerOptions.java:65)
    at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.getRpc (ServiceOptions.java:443)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.SpannerOptions.getSpannerRpcV1 (SpannerOptions.java:315)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.SpannerImpl.<init> (SpannerImpl.java:138)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.SpannerOptions$DefaultSpannerFactory.create (SpannerOptions.java:60)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.SpannerOptions$DefaultSpannerFactory.create (SpannerOptions.java:55)
    at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.getService (ServiceOptions.java:430)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.spanner.SpannerConfig.connectToSpanner (SpannerConfig.java:155)
    at com.crypto20.DeveloperSubscription.main (DeveloperSubscription.java:94)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:282)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
```

Specifying `withProjectId()` does not fix it.

Neither does upgrading all dependencies, including the ones pulled in transitively - unless I've made a mistake (I'm not accustomed with how dataflow is structured internally and what each dependency does). After updating the dependencies, not even staging the compiled project works.

I suspect there is a particular dependency which needs updating, I've tried various combinations, to no avail.

Update:

One of the things I've tried is pinning `grpc-google-common-protos` to `0.1.9` or even the most up-to-date `1.2.0`.

If I do this, not even uploading the pipeline works, since I get the following exceptions before uploading:

```
Mar 12, 2018 7:40:22 AM org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.util.PackageUtil stageClasspathElements
INFO: Uploading 120 files from PipelineOptions.filesToStage to staging location to prepare for execution.
[WARNING] 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while staging packages
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.util.PackageUtil.stageClasspathElements (PackageUtil.java:396)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.util.PackageUtil.stageClasspathElements (PackageUtil.java:272)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.util.GcsStager.stageFiles (GcsStager.java:76)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.util.GcsStager.stageDefaultFiles (GcsStager.java:64)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.run (DataflowRunner.java:661)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.run (DataflowRunner.java:174)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run (Pipeline.java:311)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run (Pipeline.java:297)
    at com.crypto20.DeveloperSubscription.main (DeveloperSubscription.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:282)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error executing batch GCS request
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.GcsUtil.executeBatches (GcsUtil.java:610)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.GcsUtil.getObjects (GcsUtil.java:341)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.storage.GcsFileSystem.matchNonGlobs (GcsFileSystem.java:216)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.storage.GcsFileSystem.match (GcsFileSystem.java:85)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystems.match (FileSystems.java:123)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystems.matchSingleFileSpec (FileSystems.java:188)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.util.PackageUtil.alreadyStaged (PackageUtil.java:159)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.util.PackageUtil.stagePackageSynchronously (PackageUtil.java:183)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.util.PackageUtil.lambda$stagePackage$1 (PackageUtil.java:173)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly (TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:111)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run (InterruptibleTask.java:58)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run (TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 404 Not Found
Not Found
    at org.apache.beam.sdks.java.extensions.google.cloud.platform.core.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue (AbstractFuture.java:500)
    at org.apache.beam.sdks.java.extensions.google.cloud.platform.core.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get (AbstractFuture.java:479)
    at org.apache.beam.sdks.java.extensions.google.cloud.platform.core.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get (AbstractFuture.java:76)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.GcsUtil.executeBatches (GcsUtil.java:602)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.GcsUtil.getObjects (GcsUtil.java:341)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.storage.GcsFileSystem.matchNonGlobs (GcsFileSystem.java:216)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.storage.GcsFileSystem.match (GcsFileSystem.java:85)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystems.match (FileSystems.java:123)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystems.matchSingleFileSpec (FileSystems.java:188)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.util.PackageUtil.alreadyStaged (PackageUtil.java:159)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.util.PackageUtil.stagePackageSynchronously (PackageUtil.java:183)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.util.PackageUtil.lambda$stagePackage$1 (PackageUtil.java:173)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly (TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:111)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run (InterruptibleTask.java:58)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run (TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 404 Not Found
Not Found
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute (HttpRequest.java:1070)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.batch.BatchRequest.execute (BatchRequest.java:241)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.GcsUtil.lambda$executeBatches$0 (GcsUtil.java:596)
    at org.apache.beam.sdks.java.extensions.google.cloud.platform.core.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly (TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:111)
    at org.apache.beam.sdks.java.extensions.google.cloud.platform.core.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run (InterruptibleTask.java:58)
    at org.apache.beam.sdks.java.extensions.google.cloud.platform.core.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run (TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Mar 12, 2018 7:40:22 AM org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AggregateFuture$RunningState handleException
SEVERE: Got more than one input Future failure. Logging failures after the first
java.io.IOException: Error executing batch GCS request
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.GcsUtil.executeBatches(GcsUtil.java:610)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.GcsUtil.getObjects(GcsUtil.java:341)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.storage.GcsFileSystem.matchNonGlobs(GcsFileSystem.java:216)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.storage.GcsFileSystem.match(GcsFileSystem.java:85)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystems.match(FileSystems.java:123)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystems.matchSingleFileSpec(FileSystems.java:188)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.util.PackageUtil.alreadyStaged(PackageUtil.java:159)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.util.PackageUtil.stagePackageSynchronously(PackageUtil.java:183)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.util.PackageUtil.lambda$stagePackage$1(PackageUtil.java:173)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:111)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:58)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this Stack Overflow post: [Error using SpannerIO in apache beam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46684071/error-using-spannerio-in-apache-beam). It's possibily related or the same issue described in the JIRA issue [BEAM-2837](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-2837).

The Stack Overflow post doesn't have an accepted answer, but I was able to resolve the issue by explicitly defining the required `com.google.api.grpc` dependency and excluding the version from `org.apache.beam`.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.api.grpc</groupId>
    <artifactId>grpc-google-common-protos</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.9</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
    <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform</artifactId>
    <version>${beam.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.google.api.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-google-common-protos</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using gradle, use the below snippet to enforce the version. This resolved my issue here.

```
 compile (group: 'com.google.api-client', name: 'google-api-client', version: '1.22.0') {
    force = true
}
```